# RRDTOOL & Retina (high DPI) screens

Tags: rrdtool

I would like to get a 2x version of a given chart (so I can have a retina @2x friendly version) the problem is that when I render the 2x version the way the data is displayed changes slightly. Has anybody had any luck producing retina friendly charts? any hints/pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `rrdtool graph` with the `--zoom=2` option.